# AS3 to PHP to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need a little help here getting data from mysql via PHP with AS3.

I've change the code a few times

AS3 Code here

```
function requestData():void {

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.bestlincs.co.uk/forum/iphone.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data as String;


urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

    function completeHandler(evt:Event):void{
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = evt.target as URLLoader;
        var resultData:String = urlLoader.data as String;

        if (resultData == "") {
            output_txt.text = "No data coming through";
        } else {
            output_txt.condenseWhite = true;
            output_txt.htmlText = "" + resultData;
        }
    }

urlLoader.load(varSend);

}
requestData();
stop();
```

PHP code is HERE

```
<?

include "../lib/forumconnect.php";


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_owner='0'");
$body="";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $body.=$row['post_body']."<br>";    
}

echo "returnBody=".strip_tags($body);
echo "returnBody=".strip_tags($body);

mysql_close();
exit();

?>
```

Now i get the error

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 9   1120: Access of undefined property event.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 26  1120: Access of undefined property varLoader.

Please can anyone shed some light on this ???

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 11 1120: Access of undefined property event.

Comment: i've updated the code above now, please check it over i get Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 9 1120: Access of undefined property urlLoader.
 3 times now

Comment: @Chezzy Don't keep editing your answer and updating it with different options you are trying. People here will loose context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all.

There is no property called `returnBody` in `event.target.data`.

You should be looking at this instead

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
var resultData:String = urlLoader.data as String;
```

So your function becomes something like this:

```
function completeHandler(evt:Event):void{
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = evt.target as URLLoader;
    var resultData:String = urlLoader.data as String;
    if (resultData == "") {
        output_txt.text = "No data coming through";
    } else {
        output_txt.condenseWhite = true;
        output_txt.htmlText = "" + resultData;
    }
}
```

Comment: now i get Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 9 1120: Access of undefined property event.
 :-(

Comment: line 9 being var varLoader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;

Comment: @Chezzy: Let me try to re-write the entire function code for you.

Comment: That would be fantastic Bijoy, i only need to receive data with this code, i will take posting back to php/mysql later

Comment: @Chezzy: I just modified the answer and added your re-written function code.

Comment: updated with your code and i get access of undefined property event now

Comment: rename urlLoader inside the function to something else.

Comment: makes no difference what so ever :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use "&" to allow the flash player to GET the variable.

```
echo "&returnBody=".strip_tags($body);
```

Edit (EXAMPLE):

```
        public static var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
        public static var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        public static var req:URLRequest;

        public static function $req() {
            req = new URLRequest("sitelink");
            l.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, $req_done);
            vars.someVar = "value";
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            req.data = vars;
            l.load(req);
        }
        private static function $req_done(e:Event) {
            l.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, $req_done);
            var $g:* = l.data;
            trace($g);
        }
```